# Could I intercept my browser's request and give it a response of my own?

Tags: browser, javascript

I'm practicing some hackery for my own hobby and I'm using my own browser as a playground.

What I'm trying to accomplish is that I want to visit a website, which of course loads a bunch of html, images, css and javascript files.

I want all of that to work as normal, except that I want to intercept the request for one specific javascript file endpoint and give my browser a custom javascript file in return.

Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: The guys over on https://sqa.stackexchange.com/ will be doing this sort of thing fairly regularly, to mock responses. You might be better off over there.

Comment: The concept is called "man-in-the-middle proxy", e.g. [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) as a ready-made implementation. Alternatively, if you know Javascript anyway, run a node http server that forwards requests (and modifies as required).